# Authenticating cross domain WCF binding

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I’m fairly new to WCF I need some help/advice on what options I have available for the following web application setup.

My WCF service is hosted within a web application which itself is accessed using Basic authentication configured in IIS.

My client sits on another domain different to the web application that is being accessed.

The code that my service is calling in the web application checks the authorisation of the current logged in user.

Call made from service to the following:

```
if (WinPrin.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
.
.
Create customer
.
.
```

My question is how should I configure my bindings if I want to be able to call my service from my client.  The data I want to pass to my service needs to be encrypted which would leans towards wsHttpBinding, but then can I can send basic authentication details to my service for it to use them to process the request? Is that possible.

I have tried the following code, but my web app is unable to pick the credentials that I pass it

Client

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();

 binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
 binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

 EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("url");

 Service1Client service = new Service1Client(binding, address);

 //details for an account on the hosting server domain
 service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "username";
 service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "password";
 service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "domain";
```

Thanks for any help or advice.